# Why should i add state?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-webflow

Hi, I get this error and i don't know why ??

> Start state is missing. Add at least one state to the flow

File : main-flow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.3.xsd">

<view-state id="start" view="start.xhtml">

</view-state>
```

File pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Add an 'end-state' and transition to it from your 'start' view-state and see if the error msg goes away

Comment: ok thinks, i solve it by using'http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd' instead of ''http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.3.xsd'

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the start-state parameter to the flow tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.3.xsd"
start-state="start">
```

An end-state is not a requirement to get this to work but of-course it is recommended to have an end state to clean up resources for that instance.

```
<end-state id="end"/>
```